# Making a planar dynamical system with JSXgraph

Tags: javascript, math, jsxgraph

I'm working on a predator-prey model for a dynamical systems book. I start by creating a dragable point for the initial condition. If I set up a second point whose coordinates are functions of the first point, I can drag one and it moves the other. I'm trying to get a 100 point orbit of the system, and I'm having difficulty. Here's a fiddle that works for a single point - https://jsfiddle.net/jford1906/gx86vbtc/21/

```
  var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {
  boundingbox: [-0.1, 3, 1, -0.1],
  axis: true,
  grid: true,
  showFullscreen: true
});

var p1 = board.create('point', [0.5, 0.5], {
  name: 'A'
});

var coords = board.create('text',
  [0.3, 2.8, function() {
    return "Initial Condition: (" + JXG.toFixed(p1.X(), 2) + "," + JXG.toFixed(p1.Y(), 2) + ")";
  }]
);


var p2 = board.create('point', [function() {
  return 2 * p1.X() * (1 - p1.X()) - 0.5 * p1.X() * p1.Y()
}, function() {
  return 4 * p1.Y() / 5 + 1.5 * p1.X() * p1.Y()
}], {
  withLabel: false,
  color: "blue",
  opacity: 1,
  size: 3
});
```

What I've tried so far is to plug each point of the orbit into an array, and have the next point run the same functions for it's coordinates as I did in the working example. It initially shows the whole orbit, but when I move the initial condition, all points except the last one in the orbit vanish. This fiddle shows how I've tried to do it - https://jsfiddle.net/jford1906/jra9g2d3/3/

```
var i; //indexing variable
var pts = [p1] //Put the initial condition in an array
for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  var p2 = board.create('point', [function() {
    return 2 * pts[i - 1].X() * (1 - pts[i - 1].X()) - 0.5 * pts[i - 1].X() * pts[i - 1].Y()
  }, function() {
    return 4 * pts[i - 1].Y() / 5 + 1.5 * pts[i - 1].X() * pts[i - 1].Y()
  }], {
    withLabel: false,
    color: "blue",
    opacity: 1,
    size: 1
  });
  pts.push(p2);
}
```

Ideas on why this might happen, or thoughts on a different approach? I've also tried putting the whole loop in a function and having that trigger when the point is dragged, but the same issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with JavaScript closures. It has been answered in https://groups.google.com/g/jsxgraph/c/Y1y1Mbd23ZQ. A very quick fix would be to define the variable `i` with `let` instead of `var`:

```
var pts = [p1] //Put the initial condition in an array
for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    var p2 = board.create('point', [function() {
            return 2 * pts[i - 1].X() * (1 - pts[i - 1].X()) - 0.5 * pts[i - 1].X() * pts[i - 1].Y()
        }, function() {
            return 4 * pts[i - 1].Y() / 5 + 1.5 * pts[i - 1].X() * pts[i - 1].Y()
        }], {
            withLabel: false,
            color: "blue",
            opacity: 1,
            size: 1
        });
    pts.push(p2);
}
```